# How do I resolve Materialize.css onblur error?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

### Materialize.css input tags onblur throw a console error.

I am building a Rails 5 app and using materialize css.  When I add an input element like this:

```
<div class="input-field">
  <label for="name">Email</label>
  <input id="name" name="project[name]" type="text">
</div>
```

I get the following error.

```
jquery.js:4411 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: required
at Function.a.error (jquery.js:4411)
at PSEUDO (jquery.js:4757)
at y (jquery.js:5275)
at a.compile (jquery.js:5414)
at x (jquery.js:5491)
at a (jquery.js:3984)
at Function.a.matchesSelector (jquery.js:4377)
at Function.filter (jquery.js:5734)
at init.is (jquery.js:5591)
at window.validate_field (materialize.min.js:6)
```

If I remove `type="text"` then the error goes away BUT the input label text stays in the way of my user input.  If I put it back in, the label text will move out of the way on focus, but I get console errors which affects the rest of my js.  Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: we need to see the code from `jquery.js:4411` and `jquery.js:475`, probably jquery is triggering some effect on that `input` tag

Comment: On materialize doc label is under input. I'm not sure but it's maybe a way. And does it surrounded by .row div?